Unable to save preferences in RStudio
whenever I try to create a new project or change the theme, I get the following error message
Unable to save preferences. Please verify that /Users/user/.config/rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json exists and is owned by user 'User'.


I'm running a fresh install of R and R studio on a mac. I located this hidden folder from the finder and gave it write access but still no luck. Any ideas?

Run ls -l rstudio-prefs.json and check if your username and group are listed.

I got -rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 219 Jul 21 16:47 rstudio-prefs.json
Then I created a root user and logged in as root, now it's working!! Wonder if it's alright to just keep using the root account.

I'd never work using a root account, that's highly risky and rather what Windows people are doing. You could try to chown that file or directory with your user:group. That's what the message in OP is actually demanding.
